# Binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 Error when using LaunchScreen.xib

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, react-native

I'm using the `LaunchScreen.xib` as my Launch Screen and yet I keep on getting this error when trying to publish the app.

Why is this and how to avoid this? Right now I have an empty xib, plain white.

Error:

> ERROR ITMS-90096: "Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 - New
>   iPhone apps and app updates submitted must support the 4-inch display
>   on iPhone 5 and must include a launch image referenced in the
>   Info.plist under UILaunchImages with a UILaunchImageSize value set to
>   {320, 568}. Launch images must be PNG files and located at the
>   top-level of your bundle, or provided within each .lproj folder if you
>   localize your launch images. Learn more about iPhone 5 support and app
>   launch images by reviewing the 'iOS Human Interface Guidelines' at
>   'https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5'
>   and the 'iOS App Programming Guide' at
>   'https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12'."

Image of my info.plist:
[image]

Comment: What is your deployment target version of iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using 7.0 as your Deployment target, so instead of Launch Screen.xib file use Asset Catalog and add all Splash screens, this will solve your problem.

Comment: Probably a good guess but it would be better to ASK in a comment before assuming this. If your theory is confirmed then add an answer but for now this is nothing but a guess.

Comment: it is an experience, not a guess.

Comment: Actually, this was the problem. Switched to 8.0 and everything got sorted out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What i have observed for some reason, Default-568h@2x.png is expected to be in root folder. Also Please make sure following points:

1. All images are in .png format.
2. If you are adding any background image in app then that should be available for all 
   device size.
3. App supports for iPhone 5/5s in all screens.

Comment: Read the question before copy and pasting an answer that you have saved.

Comment: it's not a copy paste. Moreover there is no need to prove what I did. Earlier my app got rejected & I shared my experience.